# Calculate number of times to toss (fair) coin for given results

Tags: probability

Started on introductory probability and I'm stuck on a problem I just can't figure out the approach to. If anyone can help, I would be very grateful.

"How many times do we have to toss a coin so that the probability of getting exactly 4 heads is exactly 1/10?"

As far as I can figure, this numbers can't line up for this specific problem?

Comment: This isn't really as specific as we would want it to be. Do you mean the probability of getting 4 heads in total, or the probability of ever encountering 4 heads in a row during your tosses? And do you mean _exactly_ $\frac1{10}$, or _at least_ $\frac1{10}$?

Comment: Apologies. 4 heads in total, and exactly $\frac{1}{10}$

Comment: Please insert the details to the problem in the posted text (and not only in the comments). So again, exactly four heads in total, or at least 4 heads in total? Please always insert the own thoughts on the problem. (For instance which is the probability when we toss 4, or 5,, or 6, or 7, or... times. We already have answers, that touch all possible questions starting from the setting now, although we do not have a clear question.

Comment: Tossing a fair coin $n$ times, there are $2^n$ possible outcomes, all equally likely, so the probability of any particular event will be $Q/2^n$ for some nonnegative integer $Q$. No matter what $n$ is, and no matter what the event is, this can't be exactly $1/10$, since $10$ is not a factor of $2^n$.

Comment: @Arcturus exactly $\frac1{10}$? That will never happen I think.

Answer (score 0):

This answer concerns the question: "how many tosses of a fair coin are needed to ensure that the probability on at least $4$ heads is at least $1/10$?"

---

If you toss $n$ times and the coin is fair then the probability on at least $4$ coins is $$1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)-P(X=3)\tag1$$where for every $k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ we have $P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}0.5^k0.5^{n-k}=2^{-n}\binom{n}{k}$.
So $(1)$ gives an expression in $n$.

Denoting this expression as $f(n)$ it seems that you are asked to solve the equation:$$f(n)\geq1/10$$This under the condition that $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

This can be done by brute force, especially because $f(n)$ is evidently strictly increasing.